# How can I choose which classes run in Python?

Tags: python, class, user-interface, pyqt4

I am using PyQt4 in Python 3.3, making a GUI and have multiple classes, some of which I don't want running until I have clicked a certain button to do so. How can I connect such a class to only run when the button is clicked, and not on the start-up of the program. 
Here is how I am currently connecting this class to my button within another class.

```
btns.clicked.connect(self.tableshow2)   
def tableshow2(self):
        table5.show()
```

This is the first class where the button is.

```
class CustTableSearch(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustTableSearch, self).__init__(parent)
        with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as db:
            cursor=db.cursor()
            num = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Insert TelephoneNumber', 
            'Enter TeleNum:')

table5 = CustTableSearch()
```

This is part of the class which the button activates, which runs on start-up of the python shell. I have tried putting this in a function within the class with the button, but then i can't have it show up using .show() (it's a screen with a table).

Comment: Where does the tableshow2 live? In which class?

Comment: It is in my main class which is supposed to be shown on running the program, called                                                   class ProfilePage(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ProfilePage, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

Comment: Are `CustomTableSearch` and `ProfilePage` in the same module (.py file)?

Comment: Yes they are both within the same '.py file'. I have also tried putting the CustomTableSearch class in a separate file to run it from there, but I had been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both classes are in the same module, you can create an instance of `CustomTableSearch` in `tableshow2(self)` method.

```
...
def tableshow2(self):
    self.table5 = CustomTableSearch(self)
    self.table5.show()
...
```

Comment: Great this runs the class properly from my button now, however this still doesn't prevent CustTableSearch from running by itself before using my button.

Comment: Make sure that you are not calling `self.show()` in `__init__()` of `CustomTableSearch` and remove the statement `table5 = CustomTableSearch` at the bottom of this class or not calling tableshow2 somewhere in the same class.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create the dialog only on demand, rather than creating it straight away when the module is loaded.

```
class ProfilePage(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ProfilePage, self).__init__()
        self.table5 = None
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        ...
        btns.clicked.connect(self.tableshow2)   

    def tableshow2(self):
        if self.table5 is None:
            self.table5 = CustomTableSearch()
        self.table5.show()
```

Comment: If the user closes the dialog and reopens it, the dialog will show the previous data, not the latest (in case the database is updated after closing and before reopening the dialog)

Comment: This works, however I am having the same issue as the other answer, where the CustomTableSearch class is running even without the use of my button connecting to tableshow2.

Comment: @Jurisdiction. Are you still creating an instance of it when the module is loaded? You need to remove the line `table5 = CustTableSearch()`, which is not needed any more.

Comment: @qurban. I suppose you might be right, but the code in the question is obviously incomplete, so it's not really possible to tell. Personally, I would prefer to create only one dialog and update the table separately. Doing it your way means you really need to explictly delete the dialog each time, because Qt will keep a reference to the previous dialog (since you gave it a parent).

Comment: @ekhumoro `Doing it your way means you really need to explictly delete the dialog each time`. This is not the case. Because doing it in my way, `self.table5` will contain a new reference to dialog each time the method is executed, resulting in the deletion of previously created dialog. Because if some object in the memory looses it's reference the object will be Garbage collected by the Python.

Comment: @qurban. No, it will only delete the python part. Qt will keep its own reference because you have given the dialog a parent. You can check this yourself by looking at `qApp.allWidgets()` when the application closes.